# FileNotFoundError when sorting files by size

Tags: python, filenotfounderror

I am trying create a list of image file names, sorted by the size of the file:

```
path = '/home/onur/Desktop/dataset/'

images = sorted(os.listdir(path), key = os.path.getsize)
print(images)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/onur/Desktop/image-downloader.py", line 98, in <module>
    images = sorted(os.listdir(path), key = os.path.getsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/genericpath.py", line 50, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'image_535.jpg'
```

The python file is NOT in `/home/onur/Desktop/dataset/`. It is just in Desktop so I wonder if that is the reason for the error. If so, how can I fix it?

Comment: The paths returned from `os.listdir()` are not full paths. Create the full path via `os.path.join()` to fix that.

Comment: "os.listdir" only lists filenames but not the paths. You can use "os.path.join" to prepend the path before processing the files further.

Comment: Consider using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) instead of `os.path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The problem is that [os.path.getsize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize) raises an error if the file does not exist. Because your Python script is in `/home/onur/Desktop` and the file name passed to `os.path.getsize` is just `image_535.jpg`, `os.path.getsize` looks for the file in your Desktop directory. Since the file is not there, `os.path.getsize` raises the error. You could run this to correctly test the file size.

```py
path = '/home/onur/Desktop/dataset/'

images = sorted(os.listdir(path), key=lambda f: os.path.getsize(os.path.join(path, f)))

print(images)
```